# object synchronization

Tags: java

When a synchronized block is used for synchronization on an object instance, then threads compete to get into object's implicit monitor. And once, any particular thread enters into the monitor, any other thread has to wait for entering into it. Then

```
synchronized(object){
  // some code here
  // no function call
}
```

must not enforce taking any particular type of object. Thus any object type can be used here because every object has its implicit monitor.

Kindly reply me is it true?

Comment: So polite and well-mannered!

Comment: @Josh: quite the opposite, actually - using the term "respected programmers" implies that some of us *aren't* (which assertion is true, of course).

Comment: Everyone who is sensible enough to understand that I was greeting everyone needs to be greeted yet again.
Thanks Pordon Sir, for noticing my respect for every one.
And MusiGenesis, everyone who considers himself worthy of respect is respectable.
Those who thought my respect was meant for them, were pleased
and others............

Comment: Oh my God!! He is a Lord! I swear i think you are all lost!!! Where your race lives?????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, every Java Object can act as a monitor.

And since this is such a short answer, for bonus, this is an interesting read: [Does the JVM create a mutex for every object in order to implement the 'synchronized' keyword? If not, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898374/does-the-jvm-create-a-mutex-for-every-object-in-order-to-implement-the-synchroni)

Also note that C# does something similar with their objects, **but** also have value types (which are not Monitors)

Answer (score 6):

Just keep in mind that if you have a variable that is `null`, you cannot lock it. Also, while things like `Integer` are objects, an `int` or `float` is *not*. You can lock an `Integer` or `int[]`, but not an `int`.