# How does JVM make sure only one thread can acquire the lock of an object?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Most of us know that whenever thread accesses a synchronized block of a object, JVM gives the lock of that object to the thread.
How does JVM make sure that only one thread can have access to a lock of an object?

Comment: Short answer is, the JVM asks the operating system to do it.  The long answer is a book-level topic: http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Third-Daniel/dp/0596005652/

Comment: @jameslarge Too bad the best answer is a comment.

Answer (score 3):

The JVM uses some locking feature provided by the operating system, like a semaphore object.  So the question now becomes how the operating system does it.

Usually there is hardware support for these things.  The CPU may offer a compare-and-set instruction which, while executing, sets a pin of the CPU (useful in multi-CPU architectures) or an internal line of the CPU (for single-CPU multicore architectures) which tells other hardware that the memory location currently formed on the address bus is not to be altered by anyone else.  So, the hardware architecture guarantees the atomicity of this instruction.

Once you have a guaranteed-atomic compare-and-set instruction, the rest is relatively easy: the lock object has a flag; the thread wishing to acquire the lock performs a compare-and-set instruction on that flag with a value of 1;  if the result of the comparison is true, then the value was already 1, so some other thread already had the lock.  If the result is false, then the value was not 1, so the current thread may consider itself to be the owner of the lock now.

If the operating system cannot acquire a lock on behalf of a thread, then it places the thread in a "waiting for lock" state, in which the thread will stay until the lock gets released.

Comment: There are two distinct low-level mechanisms: CAS and waiting on a condition. The acquiring thread will not busy-wait for the CAS to succeed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Correct, it will not busy-wait.  It will be added by the thread scheduler of the operating system into a table of threads which are waiting to acquire locks, so the compare-and-set instruction will be re-attempted on the next rescheduling, which will generally happen on the next thread switch.

Comment: That story implies that the thread will be blindly resumed regardless of the monitor state. I believe that the system will first realize that the condition is met (lock is free) and only then choose one of the threads in the wait set to run and acquire it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I did not intend to say anything different.  I amended my answer hoping to make it more clear.  Let me know if you think it is okay.

Comment: To rephrase my last comment: the system will not "keep retrying at regular intervals"---rather, there is a *reactive* process in place: when a thread releases a monitor, that will trigger the procedure which picks a thread from that monitor's wait set and lets it resume and acquire the lock. At least that was my understanding so far.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Hmmm, what you say makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

JVM uses Monitor pattern for this purposes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)